# How to build a login widget with Django on the starting page?

Tags: django

How to build a login form on the startingpage within a little widget on the top left?

I want to have a stylish web 2.0 like login...on the upper right sliding in (like on dropbox.com)...so far the design part...

when it comes to the views and default login behavior of django (1.4) i can't get myself to the right direction. I get the standart example to work with django.contrib.auth and so forth...
but what if i have my log-in widget on the first site:

> (r'^$', 'myproject.views.home')

I tried to integrate the form into my template (home.html) which looks like this:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        {% endif %}
        username:
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
        password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{'something'}}" />
        <input type="submit" value="anmelden" />
    </form>
```

my view looks like this:

```
def home(request):
    title='home'

    try:
         username = request.POST.get('username', '')
         password = request.POST.get('password', '')
         user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         if user is not None and user.is_active:
        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
            auth.login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/im_in/")
        else:
        # Show an error page
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/im_not/")
    except:


        return render_to_response('home.html',locals())
```

[edit]
my urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^$', 'edumin.views.home'),
)
```

**My problem:**

after submit django leads me to /login and says:

The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.

Any help or a good example of having a login on the first page...or a custom login which serves this purpose?

Comment: That's a urlconf issue. Show yours.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for asking...i added the urlconf part...you probably are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on everything I see here, you don't actually have anything at `/login/` to catch the login, but instead are trying to log in via the current URL. In that case you should completely remove the `action` attribute from the login form.

Comment: Verify that `{% csrf_token %}` actually outputs anything.

Comment: The CSRF will be failing because you don't supply the request context. Import RequestContext from django.template, then add RequestContext(request) as the last argument in render_to_response.